# Dependence between spells and spellpower

Tags: might-and-magic-heroes-6

Is there any kind of list with the dependence between spells effects and spell power?

For example I have Irina (sanctuary) level 19, with 28 spell power. At this point my tsunami stuns for 1 turn. I remember (long ago) when I first played, I managed to get the tsunami to stun for 4 turns (was pretty OP, but that's beside the point).

So my question is, is there any way to find out when the next spell "level" is achieved? A table or a formula or something?

**EDIT**:

Seems most people didn't understand what I'm asking so I'll try to rephrase: Is there any way to find out how spells depend on spell power?

Something like: you have 1 spell power lighting bolt does 10 dmg. You have 100 spell power lighting bold does 9999 damage. You have 1 spell power blind duration is 1 turn. You have 100 spell power blind duration is 10 turns.

Comment: Not sure what answer you want, you asked two questions.

Comment: @Skye Edited question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you're asking about what attributes abilities scale with and how. Abilities don't just scale with attributes, they can scale with level as well! But not all do.

There are many modifiers, and all modifiers are multiplicative. Let's look at lightning bolt as an example

lightning bolt deals 847/975/1121(+stats, +level),
So for level 1 lighting bolt, our damage is:

```
847*(stats modifier)*(level modifier)

=847*(hero_modifier*target_modifier)*(.101+.031*(HeroLevel-1))

=847*((100+HeroPower)/(100+Defense))^2.5*(.101+.031*(HeroLevel-1))
```

I recommend reading the [fan manual](http://heroescommunity.com/viewthread.php3?TID=36496), which includes what the abilities scale with and on page 240 it gives the full set of equations.

Comment: Awesome manual. I've noticed the modifiers myself, but couldn't guess formulas behind them.

Comment: They're sort of more complicated than expected(hyperbolic), but also cool to look at and think about. I also like that the manual gives ranges to each modifiers, so you know past a certain point where increasing an attribute makes no sense.

Comment: Forgot to give you the bounty :). Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Doing a bit of research into the mechanics of the game, and spending a great deal of time trying to actually find this ability in a list of player or faction abilities, I found that [Tsunami is a reputation ability](http://guides.gamepressure.com/mightandmagicheroesvi/guide.asp?ID=13279) that upgrades as you earn tear points for a mage class. [I found a user on here asking about this mechanic](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/32426/how-does-reputation-work-in-heroes-vi-blood-and-tears), if the response to that question provides any additional help.

I also found [this clever little web app](http://www.celestialheavens.com/viewpage.php?id=782) that mimics the skill progression. Not only should it give you a little more detail on all available spells and abilities, but it acts as a helpful hero planner, so you can build your hero up as you wish, and get a better idea on how you should progress / what level you need to get too.

Comment: I should have written that tsunami is a rep ability, my bad. +1 for a good answer and effort, but it doesn't answer the question (edited to be more clear, seems that most of ppl didn't understand what I'm asking).

Comment: I did originally look for a table that shows when it upgrades, but couldn't find anything. I expect a user with more personal experience will be able to answer this question better. That said, the walk-through did say that it could be upgraded to effect three spaces, up from two; not four. May have been a mistake on the writers side, though.

Comment: That table is what I was looking for and started the bounty for :). The app you posted is good (found it a few months ago actually), but it doesn't take into consideration anything beside level and chosen skills (at least I don't see any option anywhere).